# How to Prove that $(A ∪ B) \setminus (A ∩ B) = (A \setminus B) ∪ (B \setminus A)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Here is what I want to prove

$$(\mathsf A \cup \mathsf B)\setminus(\mathsf A \cap \mathsf B)=(\mathsf A\setminus\mathsf B)\cup(\mathsf B\setminus\mathsf A)$$

And here is what I've got so far

$$
\begin{align*}
(\mathsf A \cup \mathsf B)\setminus(\mathsf A \cap \mathsf B) &= (\mathsf A \cup \mathsf B)\cap(\mathsf A \cap \mathsf B)^\mathsf C \\
&=(\mathsf A \cup \mathsf B)\cap(\mathsf A^\mathsf C\cup\mathsf B^\mathsf C) \\
&=((\mathsf A \cup \mathsf B)\cap\mathsf A^\mathsf C)\cup((\mathsf A \cup \mathsf B)\cap\mathsf B^\mathsf C)
\end{align*}
$$

From this point on, I cannot figure out how to prove that the Left Hand Side (LHS) is equal to $(\mathsf A\setminus\mathsf B)\cup(\mathsf B\setminus\mathsf A)$

Comment: To downvoter: please leave a comment on why you down vote - the OP has showed effort, and the gap to answer is very small.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider that
$$
(A\cup B)\cap A^C=(A\cap A^C)\cup(B\cap A^C)=\emptyset\cup(B\setminus A)
$$
Similarly for the other term.

---

On the other hand, a “non algebraic” proof can be easier.

Suppose $x\in (A\cup B)\setminus (A\cap B)$. Then $x\in A$ or $x\in B$, but $x\notin A\cap B$. If $x\in A$, then $x\notin B$, so $x\in A\setminus B$. If $x\in B$, then $x\notin A$, so $x\in B\setminus A$.

Conversely, suppose $x\in (A\setminus B)\cup(B\setminus A)$. Then $x\in A\setminus B$ or $x\in B\setminus A$. It follows that $x\in A\cup B$. If $x\in A\setminus B$, then $x\notin A\cap B$; if $x\in B\setminus A$, then $x\notin A\cap B$.

Comment: Looks like I was missing how Distributive Property works :)

Answer (score 3):

You were almost there! It turns out that $(A\cup B)\cap A^C=B\setminus A$ and that $(A\cup B)\cap B^C=A\setminus B$.